A question on polynomial of graph weights
Background
The study of vector interactions and polynomials in graph theory provides critical insights into the structure and behavior of graphs. Let there be a set of 5 vertices, $V = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$, representing the unit vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Define the edges between any two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ by the inner product $w_{ij} = \langle v_i, v_j \rangle$, which represents the "weight" of the edge between vertex $i$ and vertex $j$. The weights of edges reflect the geometric relationship (angle) between the corresponding vectors.
Question
Consider all 3-cliques (triangles) in this graph, where $w_{ij}, w_{ik}, w_{jk}$ are the edge weights for a given triangle $\{i, j, k\}$. For each triangle, define a polynomial:
$$
x^3 - 3x^2 - (w_{ij}^2 + w_{ik}^2 + w_{jk}^2 - 3)x +w_{ij}^2 + w_{ik}^2 + w_{jk}^2 - 1 - 2w_{ij}w_{ik}w_{jk}
$$
Now, consider the minimum of the smallest roots of this polynomial across all triangles in the graph. Is this minimum always less than or equal to $\frac{3}{10}
$ for all graphs with a set of of 5 vertices, $V = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5\}$, representing the unit vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5 \in \mathbb{R}^3$?

I have done many computations, but no counterexample has ever been found.

What do graphs have to do with the problem? Is this graph always the complete graph ? If so, you can just say that you consider the polynomial for all triples of points. And because we are searching for the global minimum, It does not matter that there are $5$ vertices, we just want to find the minimum root of the given polynomial. Am I correct by saying this or do I misunderstand something?

Ok, the fact that there are $5$ vertices may actually have an impact

If $v_i=(1, 0, 0)$ for all $i$, then $w_{i, j} = 1$ for all $i, j$. The polynomial will be the same for all triple, and the only root will be greater than 3.

@caduk Thank you for your comment. There should be no parentheses in the latter terms of the polynomial. Thanks.

@caduk  The upper bound for the minimum is for all graphs with a set of 5 vertices, $V = {v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5}$, representing the unit vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5 \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

@caduk Do you have any insights on how to find the answer? Thanks.

I guess we need to find 5  vectors maximallly spaced. Maybe try the spherical code with 5 points?

@caduk  Then could you determine the bound for the smallest root in terms of the bound $\theta$ for a spherical code with 5 points? Thank you!

The spherical code is not unique for 5 points, and was not so useful, since it appears it is not good to have two points at opposite directions. Using a black box optimizer, I got the points [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.74, 0.07], [0.6, 0.36, 0.71], [0.75, 0.29, 0.59], [0.96, 0, -0.27] for a root of 0.8465673697633224. I don't know if this is the optimum, or even if it is local optimum.

@caduk  What's your 2nd vector? and how did you get 0.8465673697633224 for the minimum of the smallest roots? Thanks.

Sorry, [0.74, 0.67, 0.07]. I found the roots with a root finding algorithm.

Sorry, there was an error in my code, I'm reoptimizing, but my minimum so far is much lower, and seems to be around 0.09

After some computations, my best so far are  [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[-0.7779721523685951, 0.6175518435483857, 0.11571106545601272]
[-0.06731595456812799, -0.9897214304973406, -0.1261746895176667]
[-0.5498761766394891, -0.6179035964331466, 0.5619887328757762]
[0.8125398027428892, 0.0, 0.5829057118939106] for a minimum of 0.12853752716710184.

@caduk  Thank you for the update. Could you find out the relationship between the minimum of the smallest roots and the optimal angular bound of a PROJECTIVE spherical code with 5 lines? Thank you!

@caduk Would the optimal spherical code with 5 lines yield a minimum larger than $0.12853752716710184$? Thanks.

As I said, spherical code on 5 points are not unique, and do not achieve a better minimum, because they have points that are at near opposite directions. I believe my example is close to optimal, but hard to be sure since the problem us hard to optimize, it seems to be often stuck in local optimal or narrow valleys.

@caduk  Then how different is the "maximally spaced" required by this question from the "maximally spaced" in spherical code? Thanks.

I had the intuition that maximally spaced vectors were best when tackling this problem, but the optimum seems to be different since vectors in opposite directions don't yield good results.

@caduk  Do you know about projective spherical codes, where the angles between lines are not obtuse? Best regards.

@caduk  Is it true that the minimum is achieved only when the absolute values of the three weights are equal? Thanks!
